# Replacing a dash after a specific string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am a developing a site for a client, who is a Youth Football (Soccer) Club. They have lots of different teams, which I have created as categories in WordPress, e.g Under 7s Falcons (slug = `under-7s-falcons`). For a part of the site, I need to use the category slug to link to each Team page, however the URLs of these pages are in a slightly different format: `/under-7s/falcons`. I have been trying to use PHP's `preg_replace()` function to replace the `-` after the `/under-##s-falcons` bit with a dash so it appears as `/under-##s/falcons`. Here is my code:

```
$teamPage = preg_replace("/under-[1-9]{1,2}s-/", "/", $teamPage);
```

As you can see, I am trying to match the `-` that comes after 'under' and then two digits (each age, up to 16, but I have put 1-9 as it's easier). However, this just replaces the whole `under-##s` bit with a `/`. How would I change it so that only the `-` is replaced with the `/`?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Either a lookbehind or with `\K`, or just capture and reinsert `$1` the leading stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) for this purpose.

```
$teamPage = preg_replace("/(under-[1-9]{1,2}s)-/", "$1/", $teamPage);
```

Or you can use the `\K` escape sequence which resets the starting point of the reported match and any previously consumed characters are no longer included.

```
$teamPage = preg_replace("/under-[1-9]{1,2}s\K-/", "/", $teamPage);
```

Comment: hey, thanks @hwnd, this works perfectly. I'll look more in capturing groups :)